# Can I develop high quality games for Android/iOS using libGDX?

Tags: unity-game-engine, frameworks, libgdx, game-engine, 2d-games

All I wanna know is, "Can I develop high quality games for Android/iOS using libGDX or game engines like Unity3D would be needed?"

Comment: Your actual question being: "Can I develop high quality games?" with emphasis on **I**. Quality of an app does not depend on the underlying technology, or at least it very, very rarely is the main problem of not being able to create high quality apps.

Comment: LearnCocos2D, while I agree with your comment, I find it pedantic. The question was obviously placed by someone inexperienced, and a much better answer would be to show pros/cons of whatever tech you like.

Comment: You can create high quality games with either. Unity is faster to develop with and easier for beginners to learn, but Libgdx gives you more potential power (frame buffer objects, mixing in native UI elements, using any library you like) than the free version of Unity (but the pro version does allow all that). Cocos2d is another option. I have found it to be similar in features and learning curve to Libgdx, but it additionally has a wysiwyg editor of sorts; maybe not as nice as Unity's though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Unity3D is much more than a library (like libGDX). You get a very good editor, that allows you to see your game objects and make debugging a dream compared to building something without a visual aid.

Unity3D has another major advantage in its asset store. Whenever I want to do something new, I look into the asset store first, and usually someone else has done it, with much better quality than what I'd achieve in a small time frame.

I did this game in Unity3D: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6-5D6IkD5E and while I could have done it in many other engines, it would have taken me much longer.

Comment: "Unity3D is much more than a library (like libGDX).". Libgdx is not a library, it is a framework. Unity3d is a game engine and quite limited one because you are tied to what it offers. However, libgdx has virtually unlimited options, much better (but also harder) than unity3d. If you can't program then choose unity, otherwise libgdx all the way